# Confirm the file type (.jpg, .png)

Tags: image

I have to make sure a given file (.jpg, etc.) is in fact an image

besides just checking for extension, what would be some ways to actually confirm that it is in fact an image? or rather is this possible to do so?

does image file have certain characteristics that are identifiable from the rest of the file types?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: im using python at the moment

Comment: Windows, linux, osx, other?

Comment: Each file has a *fileheader* that will activate a *jpg* or *png* reader to generate an image. A file extension is merely used to let the os in quick scan know what thumbnail image will be used. So check the header to know if the file should be treated as an image.